# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException with Klaxon json Kotlin Library

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, klaxon

I am using klaxon with my android app (proguard enabled) This error coming with latest android version 8.0. Any Idea what causing ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unexpected character at position 2: '< (60)'


com.beust.klaxon.Parser.parse (Unknown Source:24)
cc.cc.api.JsonParser$Companion.parse (Unknown Source:15)
cc.cc.api.JsonParser$Companion$processResponse$1$2.onCompleted (Unknown Source:52)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.getResultOrThrow (Unknown Source:10)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.cancel (Unknown Source:22)
com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$EmitterTransform$1.onCompleted (Unknown Source:25)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.getResultOrThrow (Unknown Source:10)
com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.cancel (Unknown Source:22)
com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run (Unknown Source:55)
com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run (Unknown Source:14)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6541)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: your json is valid right?

Comment: @SurajNair it working fine with other Android versions. I am not getting this kind of error

Comment: Is it klaxon json library issue or android app code issue any idea?

Comment: Sorry i don't know about this issue , i m searching on it if anything find useful i will let you know

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you're trying to parse an invalid JSON string.

Comment: @Egor But during testing there is no such kind of error coming. It’s only happing on end user device. Can you say which part throwing error ?

Comment: Try to repro the issue under test by composing a JSON that contains that invalid character. To me it looks like the library is doing the right thing to fail on unexpected input, hence you need to figure out why the server sends erroneous data that can't be parsed, and probably ensure that your app handles bad data without crashing.

Comment: @Egor Thing is that In testing I never get this error. I am using third party json with my own json api. Let me test all calls agains and need to review results. Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Please file an issue at http://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/issues and include the JSON you're trying to parse. Thanks.